# regular expression to match a string in order

Tags: java, regex

I have string as follows

```
"ValueFilter("val1") AND ColumnFilter("val2") AND ValueFilter("val3")"
```

I have stored the following regex in a array. Using for loop I tried to match the pattern

```
"ValueFilter\\((.*?)\\)","ColumnFilter\\((.*?)\\)"
```

what I will do is I will replace the value in the bracket and copy it to a new string.

When I run this above regex against the string in the first loop i have XFilter so it will match both occurrence. But I want to do this in order.

Here is the i thing i want to achieve

first i want to match ValueFilter first then ColumnFilter then again ValueFilter. How can I achieve this?

**Edit** : Added Code

```
String expr = "\"ValueFilter(\"val1\") AND ColumnFilter(\"val2\") AND ValueFilter(\"val3\")\"";

String patterns = {"ValueFilter\\((.*?)\\)", "ColumnFilter\\((.*?)\\)"}

for (String pattern : patterns) {
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(expr);

    while (m.find()) {

        //do something
    }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
ValueFilter("val1")
ColumnFilter("val2")
ValueFilter("val3")
```

Comment: Can you add complete code. [mcve].

Comment: check my edit @Reddevil

Comment: @Reddevil i would suggest to change your String to the correct string `"\"XFilter(\"val1\") AND YFilter(\"val2\") AND XFilter(\"val3\")\"";` you have to escape the `"` with `\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex `[XY]Filter\((.*?)\)` with pattern and you have to loop throw the matches using :

```
String str = "\"XFilter(\"val1\") AND YFilter(\"val2\") AND XFilter(\"val3\")\"";
String regex = "[XY]Filter\\((.*?)\\)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {                                                
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**Note** you can i use `[XY]` which mean to match both `X` or `Y`,

**Output**

```
XFilter("val1")
YFilter("val2")
XFilter("val3")
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GPHsjq/1)

---

If you want to get only the value you can get the group 1 like `matcher.group(1)` instead, the output should be :

```
"val1"
"val2"
"val3"
```

---

**Edit**

> what if I have filtername as "`ValueFilter`" and "`ColumnFilter`" instead
>   of `X` and `Y`

In this case you can use `(Value|Column)` instead of `[XY]` which mean match `ValueFilter` or `ColumnFilter`, the regex should look like :

```
String str = "\"ValueFilter(\"val1\") AND ColumnFilter(\"val2\") AND ValueFilter(\"val3\")\"";
String regex = "(Value|Column)Filter\\((.*?)\\)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
ValueFilter("val1")
ColumnFilter("val2")
ValueFilter("val3")
```

#### Check code demo

Comment: what if I have filtername as "ValueFilter" and "ColumnFilter" instead of X and Y

Comment: @Reddevil in this case you have to use `(Value|Column)` instead of `[XY]` check my edit

Comment: its working but matcher.group first returns like eFilter("val1") and next time nFilter("val2") and next time eFilter("val3"). why it is not returning full filter name

Comment: @Reddevil can you share your full string please i mean the `expr`, alose what is the expected result?

Comment: what did you mean by `why it is not returning full filter name` ? what is the expected output @Reddevil

Comment: @Reddevil val1 and val2 is static or dynamic values?

Comment: @YCL_F answer you have given is working but it is not matching the whole filter like for ValueFilter("val1") matcher.group() is printing only eFilter("val1")

Comment: @Reddevil check my edit and check the code demo https://ideone.com/xdHb2L

Comment: sorry my mistake I forgot to change the bracket ..thanks